# Parse ini file using PHP with symbol

Tags: php, qt, ini

Hi I need to parse the ini file shown below using php, which is basically created using Qt [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html), I have tried the code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_parse_ini_file.asp), but seems the INI file are different format there.

Is it possible to parse INI file in below format using PHP  ?

```
[General]
Address=
Email=test@gmail.com
Password=123$
Sync=0
Loggedin=1


[Drives]
1\drive=/
1\free=281
1\size=908
2\drive=/media/New_Volume
2\free=6
2\size=7
3\drive=/media/sdb2
3\free=906
3\size=916
size=2


[Cam]
1\detection=0
1\Area.height=2.4
1\Area.width=9.5
2\detection=0
2\Area.height=2.4
2\Area.width=9.5
3\detection=0
3\Area.height=2.4
3\Area.width=9.5
size=2
```

**Update:**

Actually the above ini was working as said in below answer, and my actyual ini contains the $ symbol, that was creating the problem.

```
 [General]
    Address=
    Email=test@gmail.com
    Password=123$
    Sync=0
    Loggedin=1


    [Drives]
    1\drive=/
    1\free=281
    1\size=908
    2\drive=/media/New_Volume
    2\free=6
    2\size=7
    3\drive=/media/sdb2
    3\free=906
    3\size=916
    size=2


    [Cam]
    1\detection=0
    1\Area.height=2.4
    1\Area.width=9.5
    2\detection=0
    2\Area.height=2.4
    2\Area.width=9.5
    3\detection=0
    3\Area.height=2.4
    3\Area.width=9.5
    size=2
```

And seems I have to escape the `$` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just fine, take a look at the `php` code while the `.ini` file stays exactly as you have it.

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("settings.ini",true);
print_r($ini_array);

//will output
Array
(
    [General] => Array
        (
            [Address] =>
            [Email] => test@gmail.com
            [Password] => 123$ // note the $ sign in value here
            [Sync] => 0
            [Loggedin] => 1
        )

    [Drives] => Array
        (
            [1\drive] => /
            [1\free] => 281
            [1\size] => 908
            [2\drive] => /media/New_Volume
            [2\free] => 6
            [2\size] => 7
            [3\drive] => /media/sdb2
            [3\free] => 906
            [3\size] => 916
            [size] => 2
        )

    [Cam] => Array
        (
            [1\detection] => 0
            [1\Area.height] => 2.4
            [1\Area.width] => 9.5
            [2\detection] => 0
            [2\Area.height] => 2.4
            [2\Area.width] => 9.5
            [3\detection] => 0
            [3\Area.height] => 2.4
            [3\Area.width] => 9.5
            [size] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Actually my ini file was congaing the character '$' like Password=123$, in that case,  the php is failing. Does that mean I cannot use the character $ in ini file?

Comment: just put the whole string in quotes, ex. `Password = "123$"` and you should be good

Comment: Actually right now I cannot modifies the ini file, it was doing for some other application, so I have to read as it is, is there any way to overcome this issue from php.

Comment: update your question with an actual sample containing the special characters and I will take a look at it shortly

Comment: I just tried using the new value for the Password key and it works just fine, see updated answer

Comment: But here the ini with $ symbol not giving any output, where as removing the $ symbol print the output. My php version is  PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu with apache server. And I am doing the query from chrome browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94411/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-haris).